# Is there a way to create a tagged template used in a function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ecmascript-6

I have this function which can be used as a tagged literal:

```
function stringTemplate(strings, ...keys) {
  // Oggetto contenente i valori da interpolare
  return dict => {
    return keys.reduce(
      (acc, value, idx) => `${acc}${dict[value]}${strings[idx + 1]}`,
      strings[0],
    )
  }
}
```

and I want to use like this:

```
const template = `Foo ${'a'} baz`
stringTemplate`${template}`({ a: 'bar' })
```

but it returns **undefined**

The trick to make it work is to use **eval** like this:

```
const template = `Foo ${'a'} baz`
eval(`string = stringTemplate${template}({ a: 'bar' })`)
```

but I would like to avoid eval because the template is arriving from external APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag function works fine. Only you need to apply it directly on the template literal that you are interpolating:

```
const template = stringTemplate`Foo ${'a'} baz`;
template({ a: 'bar' });
```

In your case, the `` const template = `Foo ${'a'} ba` `` was creating a string, and `` stringTemplate`${template}` `` is the same as calling `stringTemplate(['', ''], template)`.